# Reload page every 10 seconds with the table content id

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I have a table with a list of customers and its ids. The table content will change (I load data from database).

```
<table name="myCustomers">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Name1</td>
            <input type="hidden" value="1" />
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name2</td>
            <input type="hidden" value="2" />
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name3</td>
            <input type="hidden" value="3" />
        </tr>
    </tbody>
<table>
```

My page name is test.cfm
I would like, using JavaScript or JQuery, to refresh the page every 10 seconds, but passing the input hidden value as parameter. For example, first it load the page. Then, after 10 seconds, call test.cfm?myID=1... 10 seconds later, test.cfm?myID=2 and so on.

Is it possible using JavaScript or JQuery?

Thanks

Comment: Yep, entirely possible, with the use of some ajax and some setTimeouts.  http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Comment: How can I keep getting the next "id" from my table after every page refresh?

Comment: Ajax does not perform a refresh.  Please read up on ajax with the first resource i linked.

Comment: That is the problem. I need to refresh the page

Comment: Your question states that the table changes.  That's not the entire page.  You can use ajax to reload *just* the table.

Comment: The page should change

Comment: You could also use the HTML meta tag `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">` to tell the browser to reload the page every n seconds. but you would have to handle the updating ID value.  AJAX would be the better (newer) option.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing something in JavaScript to grab data from the web server every ten seconds and print it to the table using innerHTML. Method for getting data from server depends on the format of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Gets any query string variable
function qs(variable) {
   var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var vars = query.split("&");
   for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
       var pair = vars[i].split("=");
       if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
   }
   return(false);
}

// Gets your specific query string variable and parses it as an int
function getQueryStringId() {
    var id = parseInt(qs("myId"), 10);
    return isNaN(id) ? 0 : id;
}

// Does the redirect/refresh after 10 seconds
function init() {
    var baseUrl = [location.protocol, '//', location.host, location.pathname].join('');
    var currentId = getQueryStringId();
    var nextId = currentId + 1;
    var nextUrl = baseUrl + "?myId=" + nextId;
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = nextUrl;
    }, 1000);
}

init();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
        <table name="myCustomers">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Name1</td>
            <input type="hidden"  value="12" />
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name2</td>
            <input type="hidden" value="24"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name3</td>
            <input type="hidden" value="35" class="key1"/>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </form>
<table>

<script>
//use need to use cookie or session to keep track of page number
// create an array to  store all form values
var col=0;
    url();
    var pageno;
function url(){
            var values=[];
            $("input").each(function(){
                 // insert form value into array
                values.push($(this).val());
            });
                var length=values.length;
                    var x = document.cookie;
                    var t = x.replace("username=","");
                if(t==0){
                    document.cookie = "username="+0;    
                    pageno=values[0];
                    var addr=location.pathname+"?pageid="+pageno;
                    window.location.replace(addr);
                    t++;
                    document.cookie = "username="+t;

                }
                else if(t<length){
                    pageno=values[t];
                    t++;
                    document.cookie = "username="+t;
                    var addr=location.pathname+"?pageid="+pageno;
                    window.location.replace(addr);
                    setTimeout(url,5000);
                }
            else{
            document.cookie = "username=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
            }
}
</script>   
    </body>
</html>
```